# App Workers Causing Cache to Always Report CF-Cache-Status: HIT

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-apps

I have a Cloudflare App which uses workers: https://www.cloudflare.com/apps/logflare

When that is install on my test site every request reports CF-Cache-Status: HIT in the headers.

However the logs send from the worker seem to report things as they should.

The only problem here is that I have users asking why their cache hit ratio is at 100% when using my Cloudflare app.

Just looking for the correct answer here.

I have verified this by uninstalling and re-installing the app.

Comment: Are you sure `CF-Cache-Status` is being affected, or is it only the analytics that are inaccurate? We have known bugs with analytics in the presence of Apps with Workers, which is why Apps with Workers is still in beta. But there's no way your app could cause `CF-Cache-Status` to incorrectly report a hit unless your app is explicitly modifying the `CF-Cache-Status` header. So I suspect your test cases just happened to be actual cache hits, and the analytics problem reported by the users is independent of the header.

Comment: @KentonVarda I was double checking this morning and could not reproduce so I could have been mistaken yesterday.

Comment: @KentonVarda Do you know if it's because I'm making a request to logflare.app (a domain on Cloudflare) from within the App worker?  Like if I hook up another domain outside of the Cloudflare network ... could that fix it?  Or is it all App workers no matter what mess with analytics?